# Removing duplicate records based on three cols but keeping the records with the highes value in a forth col

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, duplicates, sql-delete

I've read a lot of the questions on dealing with duplicates and they have helped me write the SQL I do have, but my quest is to remove the duplicates not based on the duplication fields, but on another field.

In my project I'm defining duplicates based on three cols being equal, but there is a forth col transaction date/time that will never* be duplicated.  I want to keep the newest transaction and throw the older ones away.

Here is what I have already 
 `SELECT Table_A.Fld1, Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4, Table_A.Date_Updated
FROM Table_A INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4 FROM Table_A GROUP BY Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4 HAVING count(*)>1)  AS Temp 
ON (Table_A.Fld4 = Temp.Fld4) AND (Table_A.Fld3 = Temp.Fld3) AND (Table_A.Fld2 = Temp.Fld2);`

This produces a duplicates list

```
FLD_reUpdates_qry
Fld2    Fld3        Fld4        Date_Updated
6   User_ID_lst 1394522856  6/21/2012 15:21:59
6   User_ID_lst 1394522856  6/21/2012 15:22:21
67  [Active?]   1099608160  6/19/2012 19:09:16
67  [Active?]   1099608160  6/19/2012 19:09:17
68  Url_lst     1107138998  6/21/2012 15:21:16
68  Url_lst     1107138998  6/21/2012 15:21:42
74  User_ID_lst 1044317178  6/21/2012 15:26:24
74  User_ID_lst 1044317178  6/21/2012 15:27:15
74  User_ID_lst 1044317178  6/21/2012 15:28:50
```

Well this is fine and dandy I have the list of duplicates, and as you can see record 74 has three duplicates. But all I want is the duplicates with the latest time.
So I have this Query..
 `SELECT max(date_updated) AS LatestUpdate, Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4
FROM Table_A
GROUP BY Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4
HAVING count(1)> 1;`

 Which produces the following list ...

```
FLD_LatestReupdates_Qry
LatestUpdate        Fld2    Fld3        Fld4
6/21/2012 15:22:21  6   User_ID_lst 1394522856
6/19/2012 19:09:17  67  [Active?]   1099608160
6/21/2012 15:21:42  68  Url_lst     1107138998
6/21/2012 15:28:50  74  User_ID_lst 1044317178
```

Ah! now I have a list of what I want to keep,  and even with record 74 I only have the latest entry. But What I really want is to DELETE the other duplicates.  And that is where I seem to have run into a mental block.  How do I write a query that will delete only the older duplicates (keeping the last one) and not any of the other non duplicated records?

Answer (score 1):

Using your query **FLD_LatestReupdates_Qry** as a subquery in this code I delete duplicated rows leaving only those records with the latest date_updated. This systax for DELETE corresponds to Sql Server, if you want it for a different backend it may need some little changes.

```
DELETE A 
FROM Table_A A
INNER JOIN 
( SELECT max(date_updated) AS LatestUpdate, Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4 
    FROM Table_A 
GROUP BY Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4 HAVING count(1)> 1 
) B
ON A.Fld2 = B.Fld2 AND A.Fld3 = B.Fld3 AND A.Fld4 = B.Fld4
WHERE A.date_updated < B.LatestUpdate
```

Comment: OK!  That's it!  This deletes only the duplicate records with the earlier times.  Thanks

Comment: Ah! I spoke too soon.  I'm using MS Access and the query create a proper list of records to delete, but won't delete them.  Further investigation has turned up the Access query's with Group on can't do table updates.  Any solutions?

Comment: ahh.. i had a feeling it was Access, this is not a minor detail and you should have said so in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have a query that selects what you want to *keep*, you can create a delete query that deletes anything not returned by that query. So, you could wrap your query like this:

```
DELETE FROM Table_A
WHERE date_updated NOT IN (
  SELECT max(date_updated) 
  FROM Table_A GROUP BY Table_A.Fld2, Table_A.Fld3, Table_A.Fld4 
  HAVING count(1)> 1    
)
```

Comment: The subquery should only contain field **max(date_updated)  AS LatestUpdate** in order for that **NOT IN()** to work

Comment: The problem with this is it deletes all the other records not just the unneeded duplicate ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here I update the SQL code to delete the duplicates leaving just the first record
You can also use this code in Access 2007 also....

```
DELETE *
    FROM Test
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT * 
                        FROM (SELECT MIN(n.ID)
                                FROM Test n
                            GROUP BY n.Projects));
```

**Test** is a Table Name..

**Projects** is a field name to be eliminate the duplicates

**n** is a object you can use the same object or change as you wish